# Assigning a numeric score to a group of SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was hoping someone could help me with the best way to do this in SQL. 
If I have about 5 select statements 
e.g.,

1) select name from payment a
join address b on a.id = b.id (if this statement score = 4)

2) select name from payment x
join address y on x.id = y.id  (if this statement score = 7)

What is the best logic to use to know which select the person belongs to and how do I assign a numeric value to that name

Comment: Your `select` statements are the same.  Hence, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by statement score?

Comment: Do you mean something like `CASE WHEN <statement1> THEN 4 WHEN <statement2> THEN 7 END AS score`?

Comment: All the statements will be different was just for example. Basically I want to have a bunch of logical test which are the select statements and then depending on the one that the person belongs to they would be assigned a score so if there are two select statements select statement 1assigns a value of 3 and select statement 2 give a value of 4 if a person meets the criteria of statement 2 the value would be 4. I am just trying to assign an arbitrary score to a person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not wrong you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN statement_score = 4 THEN 'statement_score_4'
         WHEN statement_score = 7 THEN 'statement_score_7'
         .....
       END AS identifier,
       name
FROM   payment a
       JOIN address b
         ON a.id = b.id
            AND statement_score IN( 4, 7,.. )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I totally understand your question, but maybe you can select a value in each SELECT statement that indicates which query it came from. In other words,

```
select name, 4 AS score from payment a join address b on a.id = b.id (if this statement score = 4)

select name, 7 AS score from payment x join address y on x.id = y.id (if this statement score = 7)
```